# Breaking Down JS Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to simplify my code and break it down into multiple files. For example, I managed to do:

```
socket.once("disconnect", disconnectSocket);
```

and then have a separate function called `disconnectSocket` which can access the `socket` object as follows:

```
const disconnectSocket = socket => {
  ....
};
```

I'm trying to do something similar with this pattern:

```
socket.on(EVENT_NAME, params => {
   ...
});
```

where instead I can do:

```
socket.on(EVENT_NAME, myFunc);

const myFunc = (socket, params) => {
  ...
}
```

but this is failing and saying `params is undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your working example, your callback accepts 1 argument (`params`), why do you think the function now accepts 2 arguments in your last snippet?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood - because in the first example with disconnectSocket, I'm able to pass the socket in by making it the first argument of the func

Comment: let me rephrase, how can I access both `socket` and `params` inside of `myFunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this, but your function signature is incorrect. The handler will accept only **one** parameter. Note that a few of the [built-in events](https://socket.io/docs/client-api) like `reconnect_failed` don't pass any params.

Change your signature to:

```
socket.on(EVENT_NAME, myFunc);

const myFunc = (message) => {
  ...
}
```

If you want to access the socket, then do something like:

```
socket.on(EVENT_NAME, (message) => myFunc(socket, message));

const myFunc = (socket, message) => {
  ...
}
```

I use this exact pattern:

```
socket.on(constants.events.game.deployUnit, (message) => {
    deployUnit(socket, message);
});

socket.on(constants.events.game.skipOpponent, (message) => {
    skipOpponent(socket, message);
});

socket.on(constants.events.game.logDefenderKill, (message) => {
    logDefenderKill(socket, message);
});
```

Comment: will I also be able to access `socket` within `myFunc`? I need this to pull out the socketID etc - could I do something like `socket.on(EVENT_NAME, myFunc(socket, params));` and then have this signature `const myFunc = (socket, params)`?